# ipad vs iphone differences in storyboard and segues

Tags: ipad, storyboard

This is my first iPad/Storyboard/SplitViewController and it has a table as the master and each row is a separate document for the detail view.  I am starting from the Xcode 4.2 template.

I have gotten the iPhone half to work.  I hooked up a segue from the tableviewcell and get the call:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
```

And with that I can bring up the detail view correctly.

On the iPad storyboard, I don't get the prepareforsegue call.  I have tried creating a segue between the masterviewcontroller and then tried the tableviewcell controls but can't get it to call my prepareforsegue.

I also tried:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueDetailIpad" sender:nil]; 
}
```

That will call my Segue, but the tableview doesn't have an indexPath set.  (It is set on the iPhone though).

Also, when I switchback to the iPhone version, it wants to call the same performseguewithidentifier (as above), but then I have to switch between different @"segueDetailIpad" parameters.

It seems to me I am mixing "old" and "new" models and need to find some way to
get the iPad to use the segue and not rely on the didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Hope this is enough for some suggestions ;-)

thx!

Comment: Seems like linking the segue to the navcontroller instead of the viewcontroller help this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as user589310 said I was able to solve my similar problem by embedding the `[segue destinationViewController]` in a `UINavigationController`.

For example:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue destinationViewController] class] == [UINavigationController class])
    {
        [[[[segue destinationViewController] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0] setDelegate:self];
    }
    else
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDelegate:self];
}
```

Comment: Oh I just realized that the submitter answered their own question. Well, okay.